# How Solr indexes & search works so fast?

Tags: performance, solr

Does solr saves indexes in files or memory? I have reviewed document but it mentions both, how does it work so fast if it stores indexes in files? I mean I want to understand how it basically works? Where does it store indexes, and how searches are performed so fast? If its memory does it keep indexes loaded into memory all the time, or how does it work otherwise?

I'm new to anything like this, and this is really a very basic questions which will help me to understand the technicalities involved in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you are new to the whole theme i would recommend this:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_technology
- [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(search_engine)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28search_engine%29)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index

Comment: I have gone through it, it indeed a very valuable resource and helpful for me to understand this. I think I can now focus on my specific questions for solr so I can implement it with more confident. Thanks

Comment: May be a basic question: when you index a document in Solr, is a copy of that document saved in Solr?

Comment: @bytefire no, only the text and/or metadata from that document is saved, not the document itself.